# When installing quicklisp on Windows 10, where should I put ~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/projects.conf for ASDF to find?

Tags: windows, windows-10, common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

I am trying to get Common Lisp running on my Windows 10 machine and I have run into a problem with getting `ASDF/(ql:quickload "...")` to load a project. I generated the given project with the following command (after creating a `C:\Users\ig88t\src\lisp` folder):

> (ql:quickload "quickproject")
>
> (quickproject:make-project "~/src/lisp/swatchblade/" :depends-on '(vecto hunchentoot))

Which correctly generates the project and I can view the source at `~/src/lisp/swatchblade`.

But I am unable to load it via

> (ql:quickload "swatchblade")

Instead of loading, I get an error saying

> System "swatchblade" not found    [Condition of type
>   QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND]

I am going by two manuals, one that [Xach wrote](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html) and another [tailored for Windows](https://gist.github.com/tshatrov/6765120). Xach recommends `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/projects.conf` whereas the second recommends `~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/asdf.conf`. I am currently using the version Xach wrote as it has worked for me on Linux.

Going by [the manual for ASDF](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Configuring-ASDF-to-find-your-systems.html) it seems that `~/AppData/Local/` is where I should store `.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/projects.conf`. I have tried storing it at `~/AppData/Local/config/...` as well as `~/AppData/Local/.config/...` to no avail. I noticed that Clozure CL installs some quicklisp data in `~/AppData/Local/common-lisp`, so I tried putting the `source-registry.conf.d` folder there as in `~/AppData/Local/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/projects.conf` as well but it didn't work.

I have tried a lot of different variations of placing the folder in different places but I have not managed to figure out the right one. I would really appreciate any help/suggestions by anyone using Common Lisp and Quicklisp on Windows.

I am using Clozure CL, 1.11.5, and the wx86cl64 binary which comes with ASDF version 3.1.5 in case that matters.

--- edit ---

After talking with Xach about this issue, I tried:

> (quickproject:make-project "~/quicklisp/local-projects/swatch"
>                                :depends-on '(vecto hunchentoot))

and then ran:

> (ql:register-local-projects)

but upon running:

> (ql:quickload "swatch")

it failed yet again with:

> System "swatch" not found    [Condition of type
>   QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND]

He said it might be related to [this PR](https://github.com/xach/quickproject/pull/17/files) for quickproject.

--- edit #2 ---

I recently tried using SBCL and things seemed to be working. I could create projects using `quickproject` and load them. Note that I am unable to load projects created with `quickproject` under `CCL`. However, when I restart slime/emacs, I am unable to load any projects previously created under `SBCL`.

```
; SLIME 2.20
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "quickproject")
To load "quickproject":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    quickproject
; Loading "quickproject"

("quickproject")
CL-USER> (quickproject:make-project "~/quicklisp/local-projects/test/"
                             :depends-on '(vecto))
"test"
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "test")
To load "test":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    test
; Loading "test"
[package test]
("test")
CL-USER>
```

--- intermission... restarting slime ---

```
; SLIME 2.20
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "test")
; Evaluation aborted on #<QUICKLISP-CLIENT:SYSTEM-NOT-FOUND {10034555B3}>.
CL-USER>
```

So I have no clue what could be causing the issue or how to resolve it, but it appears that creating/loading projects never works under Clozure CL and to works only within the current session in SBCL.

--- edit #3 ---

It seems I was wrong about SBCL. It seems that when I run

```
(quickproject:make-project "~/quicklisp/local-projects/test/"
                             :depends-on '(vecto))
```

It creates a folder in `C:\Users\ig88t\AppData\Roaming\quicklisp\local-projects` and not in `C:\Users\ig88t\quicklisp\local-projects`. It can load projects created within the current session as I said earlier, but is unable to find them in a new session.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a permission issue? Could you try going into settings of your emacs executable and setting it to always open as administrator and check? Don't run windows, but think you can access the settings by right clicking the binary and going to 'properties'. If that works and fixes the restart slime issue, then maybe try admin mode for CCL binary as well.

Comment: @ ˆᵛˆ: I am not sure I understand your suggestion. The problem has nothing to do with emacs. What makes you think that it might be a cause of the problem? Both CCL and SBCL are able to modify/create directories and install new libraries, so I do not think it is a permissions issue.

My problem as I understand it is related to the fact that CCL/SBCL do not seem to be able to load projects created with quickproject (it only partially works for SBCL as I have mentioned in my edited post).

Thank you for taking the time to suggest something, it is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Windows has strange permissions in my experience and sometimes creating directories works, but reading them might not. No harm in trying though? I thought of it because I remember once running ccl under Windows and modifying the file system which only worked after I put the CCL bin in admin mode.

Answer (score 3):

```
(asdf::user-source-registry :direction :output)
```